# Much time to compile

Tags: errors, align

Bonjour
I was compiling this ridiculous stuff but It take too long to compile. Is there a way to perform it?

```latex
\begin{align}
    \vert{1-2x}\vert+\vert{5x-3}\vert=4 & \iff{
\begin{cases}
&  x\le\dfrac12\\
& -7x+4=4
\end{cases} ou
\begin{cases}
& \dfrac12\le x\le \dfrac35\\
& -3x+2=4
\end{cases}
ou 
\begin{cases}
& x\ge\dfrac35\\
& 7x-4=4
\end{cases}}
& \iff{
 \begin{cases}
& x\le \dfrac12\\
& -7x=0
\end{cases}$ $\textbf{ ou }
\begin{cases}
& \dfrac12\le\dfrac35\\
& -3x=2
\end{cases}
ou 
\begin{cases}
& x\ge\dfrac35\\
& 7x=8
\end{cases}} & \iff{
 \begin{cases}
& x\le\dfrac12\\
& x=0
\end{cases} ou
\begin{cases}
& \dfrac12\le x\le \dfrac35\\
& x=-\dfrac23
\end{cases} 
ou 
\begin{cases}
& x\ge\dfrac35\\
& x=\dfrac87
\end{cases}}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry I don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: Make a small compilable document that starts with `\documentclass`, contains all the relevant packages, the code that shows the issue, and ends with `\end{document}`. (see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).)

Comment: the fragment produces `! Missing } inserted.` if I try to make a document,  it then loops forever if you try to scroll past the error.

Comment: It had a typo, I corrected it, it running normally

Answer (score 3):

The expression had multiple errors and put tex into an infinite loop.
It is hard to guess the intended layout, but this runs without error so could be the basis of a fixed version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \lvert 1-2\rvert+\lvert 5x-3\rvert=4 &\iff
\begin{cases}
  x\le\frac{1}{2}\\
 -7x+4=4
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{3}{5}\\
-3x+2=4
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
 x\ge\frac{3}{5}\\
 7x-4=4
\end{cases}\\
 &\iff
 \begin{cases}
 x\le \frac{1}{2}\\
 -7x=0
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2}\le\frac{3}{5}\\
 -3x=2
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
 x\ge\frac{3}{5}\\
 7x=8
\end{cases}\\
 & \iff
 \begin{cases}
 x\le\frac{1}{2}\\
 x=0
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2}\le x\le \frac{3}{5}\\
 x=-\frac{2}{3}
\end{cases}\\
&\text{ ou }
\begin{cases}
 x\ge\frac{3}{5}\\
 x=\frac{8}{7}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```